# How do i alert flot chart label

Tags: jquery, label, alert, flot

```
var str = $("#placeholder > .tickLabels > .xAxis > .tickLabel").html();
alert(str);
<div style="font-size:smaller" class="tickLabels"><div style="color:#545454" class="xAxis x1Axis">
   <div style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:-24px;top:60px;width:57px" class="tickLabel">Jan</div>
 </div>
```

Month name is generated dynamicallly. 
The code is showing null.
What is the way to alert the name of the month tat is in the label of a line chart.

Comment: please post you related HTML code too

Comment: What HTML code do u want?

Comment: what is .tickLabel?
please post ur code

Comment: the HTML code where you have the label...i guess from `#placeholder`

Comment: iam using flot graph to plot a line chart, in that plugin i need to know how can i pull the label names which is created dynamically!!

Answer (score 1):

There's no .tickLabels element beneath the placeholder, and the other styles, while they exist, are deprecated.  The hierarchy should go like this:

```
#placeholder > .flot-x-axis > .flot-tick-label
```

Note that this will match all the x-axis tick labels, yet `.html()` uses only the first matched element.

Comment: Iam using Version 1.1 ticklabels are found in that, but when i try alerting them, its showing 'null' in alert.

Comment: Got the Ans!! should try alerting inside the function where the graph is being drawn!!